# does ordered delivery in Cloud Pub/Sub work with Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I have dataflow job that read message from pubsub, however, it process element in the wrong order, I'm using a window in order to take the recent element but sometimes message doesn't get pulled withing the window.
one thing that could work for me is processing the message in their arrival order, but from this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-cloud-pub-sub-ordered-delivery-1e4181f60bc8) I read that :

> ordered delivery in Cloud Pub/Sub does not work with Cloud Dataflow at this time...

the article is written in 2020 and in the officiel documentation I don't see a limitation of using pubsub ordered delivery
Thus, anayone know if it's supported in dataflow or not as mentioned in the article ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pub/Sub's ordered delivery is not compatible with Dataflow, no. If you start up a Dataflow pipeline with a subscription that has ordered delivery enabled, you should see a warning in the log indicating that while the pipeline will operate, order may not be preserved.

Comment: Is there any workaround to read messages from PubSub with ordering key ? Or is there anything planned by Google to support it one day ?